# How to ignore symbols & spaces during palindrome code in C

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    int l = 0;
    char a[] = "Madam, I'm Adam.";
    int h = strlen(a) - 1;
    while (h > 1) {
        if (a[l++] != a[h--]) {
            printf("%s is not a palindrome\n", a);
            return 1;
        }    

    }

}
```

This would work for strings like "madam" without any symbols. Is there a way to ignore all the symbols like ".", " ", "'", in fact, all non-alphanumeric characters. Is there a way make this work?

Comment: This program won't even work for `abcba`. It'll immediately exit with return value `1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `isalnum` function to test for alphanumeric characters.  If you come across one that is not, increment/decrement your index as necessary until you find one that is.

```
while (l<h) {
    while (!isalnum(a[l]) && l<h) l++;
    while (!isalnum(a[h]) && l<h) h--;
    if (tolower(a[l++]) != tolower(a[h--])) {
        printf("%s is not a palindrome\n", a);
        return 1;
    }
}
printf("%s is a palindrome\n", a);
return 0;
```

Comment: Seems to seg fault?

Answer (score 0):

The isalnum check will check if a character is alphanumeric or not.  tolower will lower case the character before comparing.  I added those checks and some logic for corner cases.  See if this works.  It works on my mac.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    int l = 0;
    char a[] = "Madam, I'm Adam.";
    int h = strlen(a) - 1;
    int match = 0;
    while (h > 1 && l <= h) {
        if (!isalnum (a[h])) {
            h--;
            continue;
        }
        if (!isalnum (a[l])) {
            l++;
            continue;
        }
        if (tolower(a[l++]) != tolower(a[h--])) {
            printf("%s is not a palindrome\n", a);
            return 1;
        }
        match = 1; /* at least one alphanum haracter match */
    }

    if (match == 1) {
        /* We need at least one true alphanum character match */
        printf("%s is a palindrome\n", a);
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        printf ("String of special chars %s \n", a);
        return 1;
    }
}
```